# Обрезка текста с добавлением многоточия

Tags: css

Здравствуйте! Как мне сделать, что бы текст, который не вмещается в блок, не переносился на новую строку, а обрезался с добавлением многоточия?

```css
p {
   border:1px black solid;
   width:20%;
   white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>
   123 123 123
</p>
```

Comment: Не понял вопроса :)

Comment: при нехватки места чтобы текст не переносился на новую строку а пропадал оставляя моготочие

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого есть специальный стиль `text-overflow`

```css
div {
   width: 200px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 5px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
   Текст: ляляля у меня в шкафу есть трусиля
</div>
```

Comment: а если длинный текст ? скажем в пять строчек надо перенести и на пятой строе получится сделать  `text-overflow: ellipsis;` ?

Comment: text-overflow работает согласно размерам блока и то что не влезет в него, через свойство ellipsis добавиться троеточие. если вам надо после определенного количества знаков поставить троеточие, то это только javascript